# etcd: Max Storage Size Update

Tags: etcd

Can anyone confirm whether the improvements mentioned [How Does Alibaba Ensure the Performance of System Components in a 10,000-node Kubernetes Cluster?](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-does-alibaba-ensure-the-performance-of-system-components-in-a-10000-node-kubernetes-cluster_595469) have actually been included in etcd 3.4.0?

Docs still say the recommended limit is 8GB. Article says the limit has been increased.

Comment: I see the question has been edited and downvoted. What was wrong with it? Should I delete the question? Was it the wording?

Comment: You are requesting experience with a web article, which we all have. What is *exactly* your problem?

Comment: @bjoster I edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, it's *a lot* clearer no (at least to me), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned [alibabacloud article](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-does-alibaba-ensure-the-performance-of-system-components-in-a-10000-node-kubernetes-cluster_595469) links to a [CNCF blog post](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2019/05/09/performance-optimization-of-etcd-in-web-scale-data-scenario/?spm=a2c65.11461447.0.0.7852620d9fl8AL) with regards to optimizations of the idle page management algorithm of etcd. The CNCF blog post mentions a [pull request](https://github.com/etcd-io/bbolt/pull/141) for the changes. That pull request has been merged in the mean time. So, yes, I assume that the improvements have been merged into etcd (bolt to be more precise).

The [etcd dev guide](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3.12/dev-guide/limit/) states:

> 8GB is a suggested maximum size for normal environments

I would emphasise `suggested` and `normal environments`. I haven't found any resources on actual limits. So in my reading the suggested maximum size doesn't necessary mean that those improvements haven't been implemented. I assume it is recommend because it is enough for the average use case.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I am vetting options for a proof of concept, and etcd has a few interesting capabilities I’d like to use. It’s usually associated with Kubernetes, and probably most documentation is skewed towards its usecases. I felt I had to ask before venturing into a dead end. I’m also curious if a restart with a new storage limit configuration is enough to increase it should need be.